# Detect a redirect

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I am using rewrite rules to redirect some of my pages to another website. Is there a way to detect a redirect inside of the current page, so I can pop up a message saying the user is being redirected to a new website?

This is IIS redirect, done from C# .net application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, as Apache is over PHP, PHP have no control of the redirects being done by Apache.

Comment: What about IIS redirects?

Comment: Sorry but this was not specified :)

Comment: But I think it is the same, if the redirect is done by the server, the language you are using has no control.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: I attached a query string value at the end of redirect (Example: test.com?redirect=y) Later, in the destination website, I wrote a javascript to look for the url param value to display pop up.